# Custom column serilog with sink.MySQL

Tags: serilog

how can i custom column in Sink.MySQL with appsetting.json configuration?

i try to use

```
"columnOptionsSection": {
                    "customColumns": [
                      {
                        "ColumnName": "UserId",
                        "DataType": "nvarchar",
                        "DataLength": 450,
                        "AllowNull": true
                      },
                      {
                        "ColumnName": "UserName",
                        "DataType": "nvarchar",
                        "DataLength": 256,
                        "AllowNull": true

                      }
                    ]


                  }
```

but don't work.

Comment: (I have not use Serilog with MySql but these questions may either help you to find the problem or asist someone else in narrowing it down with you) What error message do you see, what sink and version are you using, does the rest of the message get recorded, have you created the columns and/or can you link to something in the instructions that suggests you don't need to. Does the user account have access to add columns if it is supposed to do that itself rather than you?

Comment: i use serilog.Sink.MySQL v4.0.0.
I don't have any kind of error, when I go to do the customization of the columns, it creates the standard table without going to create or modify

Comment: if i use Seriog.Sink.MSSqlServer all work

Comment: I solved it by installing the MariaDB sink

Comment: If you can add another detail or two, then that's a valid self-answer, i.e. answer with what you did, and accept (in general it's suggested to provide as detailed an answer as you can - i.e. the answer you wish you'd seen at the start!)

Comment: someone was able to solve it without having to change to mariadb?? , I think the nuguet does not have those options in version 4.0, they just added the Template column in version 4.6